# Creating a second sysadmin on SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

When creating a SQL Azure server, we get one 'superuser' that has full access to all databases. We would like to create more of these users, but not quite sure how.

We have looked at the following article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336235.aspx

It allows us creating new logins via:

```
-- first, connect to the master database
CREATE LOGIN login1 WITH password='<ProvidePassword>';
```

Then we can add the 'dbmanager' and 'loginmanager' roles:

```
-- first, connect to the master database
CREATE LOGIN login1 WITH password='<ProvidePassword>';
CREATE USER login1User FROM LOGIN login1;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'dbmanager', 'login1User';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'loginmanager', 'login1User';
```

The new user can now connect to our SQL Azure server and see all the databases. However, the user is then unable to connect to individual databases. A workaround is to create a user mapped to a new login in *each* database and grant that user `db_owner` rights, but that is cumbersome and requires maintenance.

Is there an easy way of creating another sysadmin user in SQL Azure?

Comment: This is not possible - official documentation here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-logins/. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437045/create-an-new-administrator-level-login-in-azure-sql

Comment: It's cumbersome if you are doing it from the portal. You can create scripts for simplifying it. Or use arm templates to create the admin user during provisioning database

Answer (score 6):

There is only 1 server admin account allowed for Azure SQL Databases. However, you can add an Azure Active Directory (AAD) group as the Active Directory admin, enabling multiple AAD users to be server admins. More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview) about using AAD on Azure SQL Database.

Comment: They aren't exactly the same, but it's the closest equivalent in Azure SQL Database. From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage : "This login is granted full administrative permissions on all databases as a server-level principal. The login has all available permissions and can't be limited."